# Display List of Records by using standard controller I have displayed by using with pageblocktable can we do this by using with controller?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" tabstyle="account" sidebar="false">
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:form >
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"/>
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:panelGrid>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" id="list">
        <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: If you are asking "Can I use a custom list created in a controller to drive my `pageBlockTable`', the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
List<account> accountList = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 20];
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountList);
```

This link could be helpful

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm